# Webhook not posting to Teams

Tags: c#, webhooks, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been using this webhook method for a little over six months. I haven't had a problem with it, but since December 16th it has not been posting a message to Microsoft Teams. I instead see an error in my code saying the task has been canceled. I have tried making a new webhook, comparing it to Postman (which works), and adding the project to the solution that was originally referencing it by a NuGet package.

This is the stack trace error that I'm getting

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at ErrorLogger.Logger.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DWillaford\source\repos\ErrorLogger\Logger.cs:line 96

```
try
            {
                string json = "{'@type': 'MessageCard', 'themeColor': '0076D7', 'title': 'Error in " + ProjectName +
                    "', 'text': '" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + exception + Environment.NewLine + stackTrace + Environment.NewLine + "'}";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var responsen = await client.PostAsync(url,
                        new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                    var test = await responsen.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                return "Error has been posted into the teams";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in connecting or posting data to microsoft teams " + e.Message);
                return "Error hasn't been posted to Teams";
            }
```

Comment: If its working with POSTMAN, then i dont think any issue from API perspective. I would suggest you to debug it with NGROK which will provide pointers for you to move forward. Also try to see what if you create a new webhook, does it works?

Comment: I tried creating a new webhook and that didn't work. Would Fiddler work for this situation as well?

Comment: As suggested try the NGROK tunneling. Yeah, you can use POSTMAN/Fiddler/Graph Explorer to test the API call.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Dev is correct , you can use POSTMAN/Fiddler/Graph Explorer to test the API call. Could you please confirm if the issue is still persisting.